# calling batch from apex class

Tags: salesforce, apex

```
global class BatchClassForPDFGeneration implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
public static string strFileDescription='codes';
private Order__c OrderDetails;
private List<ResponseWrapperData.orderItems> OrderLineItems;

public BatchClassForPDFGeneration(List<ResponseWrapperData.orderItems> OrderLineItems,Order__c OrderDetails){
    this.OrderLineItems=OrderLineItems;
    this.OrderDetails=OrderDetails;
}
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    String query = 'Select id from Order__c where id=\''+OrderDetails.id+'\' limit 1';
    return  Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<sobject> scope) {     
}  
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

    system.debug('Process End');
}}
```

Now calling this batch from apex class

```
  // call this method when voucher type is PDF
public static void createGiftCardPDF(ResponseWrapperData.Response ResponseObject,Order__c OrderDetails){

    // call batch class to generate pdf
    GC_BatchClassForPDFGeneration giftCardBatch=new GC_BatchClassForPDFGeneration(ResponseObject,OrderDetails);
    Database.executeBatch(giftCardBatch,200);
}
```

getting the following error

> Constructor not defined: [BatchClassForPDFGeneration].(ResponseWrapperData.Response, Order__c)

Comment: 18:17:29:433 FATAL_ERROR System.AsyncException: Database.executeBatch cannot be called from a batch start, batch executes, or future method.  getting this error when performing an action in ecxecute

Answer (score 0):

You defined the constructor of your batch as `BatchClassForPDFGeneration(List<ResponseWrapperData.orderItems> OrderLineItems,Order__c OrderDetails)`.

But you're calling it as

`GC_BatchClassForPDFGeneration(ResponseWrapperData.Response ResponseObject,Order__c OrderDetails)`.

1st parameter is incompatible type so compiler complains. There's no constructor that takes the wrapper. Either add new one (it's OK to have mutliple constructors taking different arguments or no arguments at all) or change the parameter.

And batch can't be called from another batch (or more generally - another asynchronous operation). Do you have `@future`, Queueable, Schedulable or something like that that's calling `createGiftCardPDF`?

Comment: Yes actually I am doing a web callout from future than tried to calling batch to update the data in salesforce, but due to the limitation I have to go for the queueable apex, any other idea you have?

Comment: Also, does anyone know how to send an email notification after the queueable job is processed as I am checking the status it's saying 'Queued' not completed.

Comment: You'll have to ditch the @future. You can make callouts from batch, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm search for `Database.AllowsCallouts`. And if you go with batch you can put email sending in `finish`?

Comment: Thanks for the info, but right now I succeeded to send the mail after the queueable job. Sending mail on update result success.